# How do I reverse this process?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

Okay, so I am very new to this and I previously wanted to learn how to delete a certain folder using batch files. You can check out the situation at: 
[How do I make a batch file delete it's own directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624147/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-delete-its-own-directory/40624598#comment68589816_40624598)

The problem is that one person recommended that I use this line of code:

```
start /b "" cmd /c rd /s /q "%~dp0"
```

And now I'm getting errors with a lot of other batch files that I'm making and I believe that this line of code is the cause. Now here's my question: Is there a way to reverse this line of code?

Comment: What do you mean by reverse?

Comment: Like undo it or get rid of anything that it did to my computer.

Comment: That is what backups are for.

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Did you look to see if there are any files in the Recycle Bin that you can restore? (Sorry, not a windows expert, just a guess, so good luck).

Comment: I was implying that maybe there was a line of code that I could put into command prompt that could undo the process that I just ran.

Comment: This is why you should ALWAYS test this kind of stuff on a VM for which you have a recent checkpoint. If you toast something you just restore the VM to the desired checkpoint.

Comment: You can use the GUI. See *Previous Versions* in help.

Comment: What GUI are you talking about?

Comment: See Help. What else.

Answer (score 0):

An example:
If batch is found in `"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\uTorrent"`, the delete string is:

```
start /b "" cmd /c RD /s /q "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\uTorrent" 2> NUL & exit /b
```